# get every item in getParameter() using JSONArray in Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

```
String str = request.getParameter("dat");
```

How can i iterate through my array, its look like this :

`[{"orange":["1.00","5"]},{"apple":["2.00","5"]}]`

I want to have the 1st item and 2nd item...

`on first loop`

```
 setName(get(i))//orange
  setValueget(i))//1.00
  setStock(get(i))//5
```

because I want it to pass to another object class of Type Fruit(java class).

class Fruit contains

```
setName(arg);
setValue(arg);
setstock(arg);
```

can somebody redirect me to solution?

Comment: A JSON array is deserialized as a List.  You can index through it like any other List.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip) is the jar file I used.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
    String fruit = keys.next(); //Here you can get "orange" or "apple"
    System.out.println("The current fruit is "+fruit);
    setName(name);//setName here
    JSONArray fruitArray = object.getJSONArray(fruit); // I assume that you only have one json array in Each object.
    for(int j=0;j<fruitArray.length();j++){
        String numberString = fruitArray.getString(j);
        if(j==0){
            setValueget(numberString);// setValueget here
        }else{
            setStock(numberString);// setStock here
        }
        System.out.println(numberString);
    }
}
```

With your json string, I got result:

`The current fruit is orange
1.00
5
The current fruit is apple
2.00
5`

Comment: please see my edited post, i dont want it to store on another JSONArray, and getJSONArray is not working or invalid methodname

Comment: The method fromObject(String)and getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray. got this error

Comment: I still dont get some method, can you give me the link of the jar files fr JSON please? i probably using the wrong jar

Comment: also wheres the orange and apple string?

Comment: See the edited answer, I added the link for the `jar` file and where to get `orange` and `apple`.

Comment: another one so i can solve my problem, can you give me example of that using javax.json-api1.0. jar or javax.json-1.0.jar

Comment: also `jsonString` what goes inside here?

Comment: `jsonString` is the json string you're going to parse, which is `[{"orange":["1.00","5"]},{"apple":["2.00","5"]}]`

Comment: ok sir ? can you give me exqample using classes in this jar,javax.json-api1.0. jar or javax.json-1.0.jar

Comment: I added all my testing code, you need to import the `jar file` first.

Comment: Yes,i got it, but i want the file above to be used, do you know how to use them>

Comment: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TUdLU9vdqc) is a tutorial of how to import the jar file.

Comment: no i want to loop,my json array using this ar,javax.json-api1.0. jar or javax.json-1.0.jar ,and not thhe one you are posting sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58671/discussion-between-zhenxiao-hao-and-bumbumpaw).

Answer (score 1):

Hi Niang Try this code to get data from json and before run it download this jar file for JSONArray class

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonlibjar.htm

```
try{
        String str = request.getParameter("dat");
        JSONArray array = JSONArray.fromObject(str);
        for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator<String> keys = object.keys();
            JSONArray fruitArray = object.getJSONArray(keys.next()); 
            String numberString=null;
            for(int j=0;j<fruitArray.size();j++){
                numberString= fruitArray.get(j).toString();
                out.println(numberString);
            }
        }
    }catch(JSONException jex){
        jex.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I got this error sir ,The method fromObject(String) is undefined for the type JSONArray, The method getJSONObject(int) is undefined for the type JSONArray

Comment: first you need to download jar file from above link then put it to lib dir and set class path because fromObject(String) and getJSONObject these methods come from external jar